# Can someone confirm this htaccess is valid?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have the following in an .htaccess file on my server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i'm slightly confused as to what this is doing with the index.php. It looks to me that its rewriting the url twice to index.php? Is that correct, we have an issue with our server spawning lots of processes for index.php and im currently looking into where this could be being caused.

These are the log lines that are causing me to worry:

```
Jun 19 15:06:34 Server lfd[9809]: *Excessive Processes* User:ftpew1ng Kill:0 Process Count:14
Jun 19 15:06:34 Server lfd[9809]: *User Processing* PID:398 Kill:0 User:serveruser Time:560914 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/serveruser/public_html/index.php
Jun 19 15:06:35 Server lfd[9809]: *User Processing* PID:19556 Kill:0 User:serveruser Time:455723 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/serveruser/public_html/index.php
Jun 19 15:06:35 Server lfd[9809]: *User Processing* PID:32005 Kill:0 User:serveruser Time:687537 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/serveruser/public_html/index.php
Jun 19 15:06:36 Server lfd[9809]: *User Processing* PID:29603 Kill:0 User:serveruser Time:341166 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/serveruser/public_html/index.php
Jun 19 15:06:36 Server lfd[9809]: *User Processing* PID:19129 Kill:0 User:serveruser Time:342362 EXE:/usr/bin/php CMD:/usr/bin/php /home/serveruser/public_html/index.php
```

And so on..

Answer (score 0):

That is a standard WordPress rewrite block for "pretty permalinks," and it is not rewriting `index.php` twice.

If you have server issues from too many processes hitting `index.php`, look at the IPs accessing the server and see if they are consistently one or more IPs. Check https://www.projecthoneypot.org/search_ip.php to see of they are known spammers.

And take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks and  http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Comment: Thanks for confirming that! I have had a look at the apache logs and the visits to the site do not match the times that the errors are being logged (see above, I have copied the error im seeing)

Comment: Peer1 -  its a managed server from them. However we have not been getting great support from them.

Comment: If it's managed, you have to deal with them. They have to tell you where the traffic is coming from.